# What problems might arise when adding JComponents to a component

Tags: java, swing, components, awt, jcomponent

I am making some changes to an existing application whoose screens have been implemented by using awt components. Using swing in the new elements will make life easier but i know that there are some problems of mixing swing and awt components.

What i would like to know is:

**Prior to java 6 what problems might arise when someone adds swing components to an awt container?**
(My appliation has custom mdi which every window is an awt panel. What I would realy like to do is use the same awt panel as my window and implement everything inside of it with swing using java 1.5)

In some forums people says that after java6u? some of the problems of mixing awt and swing components how been fixed. is there any problem still exists that you know of ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [Mixing Heavyweight and Lightweight Components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html) for answers to both your questions.

Here is an example of the problem.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have added some extra information. Could you please check the question again?